# Raspberry Pi Web Simulator- Azure IoT Hub- blank chart

Tags: azure, raspberry-pi, azure-iot-hub

[image]I'm using Raspberry Pi simulator with IoT hub azure, I followed the steps correctly but when I checked the chart, I got a blank chart, even I set the connection string and Device Id and consumer group on the web settings.

PS: I can see the messages in Raspberry simulator and Azure IoT tools with visual studio code.

any advice?

thanks in advance

Comment: What steps are you talking about?

Comment: Visualize real-time sensor data from Azure IoT Hub using Azure Web Apps

Comment: there are the steps that i talked about, https://tlaothong.gitbooks.io/azure-iot-workshop/content/iot-hub-live-data-visualization-in-web-apps.html

Comment: Try setting the "WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION" app setting to "8.11.1".  I believe to remember that I had to make that change to make the sample work a long time ago.